# AdMob UnityException in Rewarded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, admob

I connect the AdMob SDK / Rewarded and get a Crash Report when the Ads finishes viewing.
When the ads ends, HandleUserEarnedReward should be called, but it doesn't.

```
Unity 2020.3.4f1
GoogleMobileAds-v5.4.0

Autoconnected Player UnityException: get_isActiveAndEnabled can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.
  at UnityEngine.UI.Graphic.SetVerticesDirty () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UI.Text.set_text (System.String value) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at GameUtilities+String.ToText (UnityEngine.UI.Text text, System.String content) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at GameManager.SetDiamond (System.Int32 diamond) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at GetFreeCoin.ActivateFreeCash () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at AdsControl.TypeOfReward () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at AdsControl.HandleUserEarnedReward (System.Object sender, GoogleMobileAds.Api.Reward args) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs].Invoke (System.Object sender, TEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs].Invoke (System.Object sender, TEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy.Invoke (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.InvokeJavaProxyMethod (UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy proxy, System.IntPtr jmethodName, System.IntPtr jargs) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: GoogleMobileAds.Android.RewardedAdClient.onUserEarnedReward(System.String,System.Single)
  at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy.Invoke (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.InvokeJavaProxyMethod (UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy proxy, System.IntPtr jmethodName, System.IntPtr jargs) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

Unity Code:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using GoogleMobileAds.Common;



public class AdsControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static AdsControl _instance;
    public static AdsControl instance { get { return _instance; } }
    private RewardedAd rewardedAd;
    public string rewardedAd_Android;
    public int timesFailed;
    public static int typeOfReward = 0;


    protected AdsControl()
    {
    }


    public void Awake()
    {
        if (FindObjectsOfType(typeof(AdsControl)).Length > 1)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
       
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });

        this.rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(rewardedAd_Android);

        this.rewardedAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardedAdLoaded;
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad;
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdOpening += HandleRewardedAdOpening;
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToShow += HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow;
        this.rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += HandleUserEarnedReward;
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardedAdClosed;

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build(); // Create an empty ad request.

        this.rewardedAd.LoadAd(request);  // Load the rewarded ad with the request.
        return;
    }


    public void RewardedAd_Preload()
    {
        this.rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(rewardedAd_Android);

        this.rewardedAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardedAdLoaded;
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad;
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdOpening += HandleRewardedAdOpening;
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToShow += HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow;
        this.rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += HandleUserEarnedReward;
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardedAdClosed;

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build(); // Create an empty ad request.

        this.rewardedAd.LoadAd(request);  // Load the rewarded ad with the request.
        return;
    }


    public void BoostRewardedAd_Show() //Action<ShowResult> onFinish = null)
    {
        if (this.rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.rewardedAd.Show();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            ShowNotification();
            RewardedAd_Preload();
        }
    }

    public void ShowNotification()
    {
        Notification.instance.Warning("No available video at the moment.");
    }


    public void HandleRewardedAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (timesFailed)
        {
            case 0:
                Invoke("RewardedAd_Preload", 5);
                print("timesFailed, 5");
                break;
            case 1:
                Invoke("RewardedAd_Preload", 10);
                print("timesFailed, 10");
                break;
            case 2:
                Invoke("RewardedAd_Preload", 15);
                print("timesFailed, 15");
                break;
            case 3:
                Invoke("RewardedAd_Preload", 20);
                print("timesFailed, 20");
                break;
            default:
                Invoke("RewardedAd_Preload", 25);
                print("timesFailed, 25");
                break;
        }
        timesFailed++;
        RewardedAd_Preload();
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdOpening(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        RewardedAd_Preload();
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        RewardedAd_Preload();
    }

    public void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, Reward args)
    {
        string type = args.Type;
        double amount = args.Amount;
    }
}
```